Status of R Journal
This might be a bit off-topic, but maybe someone has information about the current status of the R Journal.
The last issue listed on the website is from Dec 2023, so I wonder whether the journal is still active. The graphic on the home page showing the number of pending submissions only goes til 2022:

but it indicates that there might be a runaway problem leading to an ever growing stock of pending submission that might some day no longer be manageable. Whether this is related to the lack of issues in 2024 is mere speculation, however. The website has no comments or hints about a problem.
Is there anywhere some information what is (not) going on?

I went and added the [tag:references] tag, but feel free to remove it if you feel it does not fit. And yes, I absolutely believe this is on topic here.

We have one of the executive editors here (Rob Hyndman) as an active user in the community. Maybe perhaps he could add some info, if he thinks it is necessary.

@User1865345: good point, thanks! I just sent Rob an email to point him to this thread.

I am sure Rob would respond. Please if that happens, make it an answer. @StephanKolassa

Thanks a lot for posting this, I've also been wondering this question.  I emailed the Rjournal a while ago but did not get a response.  Glad to see the responses below confirming the journal is still active!

I am one of the executive editors of the R Journal, and I will become the managing editor in January 2025.
There has been a delay in the process between articles being accepted and being published in an issue. This has now been resolved. The first three issues for 2024 should all appear soon.
The date of an issue corresponds to the quarter in which the papers were accepted for publication. So the fourth issue for 2024 should appear in the first quarter of 2025.

Emi Tanaka, member of editorial board of the R journal, answering the question "is the R journal still accepting new submissions? Doesn't seem to have been an issue published in nearly a year", said on Bluesky (8 October 2024):

Actually the last issue was published a few months ago. The issue date
lags behind. I believe the current chief editor is/was processing the
next one so the next one should come out soon

Hadley Wickham (former editor-in-chief in 2013), answering a similar question, said (30 November 2024):

They’re running behind but working on a plan to catch up. It’s
definitely still active

In addition, you can find this recent presentation (2024) on Youtube by the editor-in-chief Mark van der Loo, where he presents the journal internal working and history, and discusses future plans: https://youtube.com/watch?v=eupuhF7XeVM.
Finally, if you have a look at their github account, their internal tools for publication look like they are in active development (e.g. https://github.com/rjournal/rjtools), with some updates dating from a couple of weeks ago at the time I'm writing this answer.
All of this doesn't hint to the journal being inactive :)
